# How to configure dry run and log level options via XML in Google Analytics v4 SDK for Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

The [parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/parameters) documentation for the XML configuration file used by the Google Analytics v4 SDK (as found in the Google Play Services 4.3.23 release) says that `ga_dryRun` and `ga_logLevel` are valid attributes in the tracker file. Here is my `res/xml/default_tracker.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="ga_dryRun">true</bool>
    <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
</resources>
```

When I set this config file on a new tracker and run my app, I see the following in the log:

```
04-30 13:05:55.303  29266-29266/com.example.app W/GAV3﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: bool configuration name not recognized:  ga_dryRun
04-30 13:05:55.303  29266-29266/com.example.app W/GAV3﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: string configuration name not recognized:  ga_logLevel
```

Are there updated attribute names to use? Is configuring these features via XML no longer supported (they worked in the v3 SDK)?

I know I can set both the dry run and log level options from Java, but it would be nice to be able to define these in the XML files so I could use different files for different build variants.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From your setup, it looks like you are specifying the settings in a tracker configuration.

The values of `ga_dryRun` and `ga_logLevel` are global settings for the app and not specific to a particular tracker from v4 onwards. Can you make sure that you are following the steps written in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html)?

To quote, Use the following to setup the configuration:

> In AndroidManifest.xml
>
> ```
>  <meta-data
>    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
>    android:resource="@xml/analytics_global_config" />
> ```
>
> In analytics_global_config.xml
>
> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <resources>
>    <bool name="ga_dryRun">true</bool>
>    <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
>  </resources>
> ```

Comment: Ah, I see. I must have overlooked that Javadoc. It is not evident from the following table, which parameters are global and which are per-tracker: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/parameters

Comment: Yeah, going through the same pain to migrate to v4 - two XML configuration files, two sets of documentation. Adding two links to that clarifies what @Avi said, one for Tracker and one for GoogleAnalytics singleton.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker.html

Comment: And again, the parameters belonging to each trackers `MUST` be written down in the official document explicitly!